# Visual Studio virtual folders in Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, virtual, solution, subdirectory

Is it possible (native or via extension) to group elements in Solution folders in virtual subfolders?
e.g.:

```
ArticleGalleryItemPhone.axml
ChangePasswordPhone.axml
ChangePasswordTablet.axml
DeviceBigListItemPhone.axml
DeviceBigListItemTablet.axml
FirstLaunchGalleryItemPhone.axml
FirstLaunchGalleryItemTablet.axml
FirstLaunchPhone.axml
FirstLaunchTablet.axml
ForgotPasswordPhone.axml
ForgotPasswordTablet.axml
HeaderPhone.axml
HeaderTablet.axml
HomePhone.axml
LoginPhone.axml
LoginTablet.axml
OutOfCoffee.axml
```

should be displayed with filter *Tablet and *Phone like:

```
Phone
    ArticleGalleryItemPhone.axml
    ChangePasswordPhone.axml
    DeviceBigListItemPhone.axml    
    FirstLaunchGalleryItemPhone.axml    
    FirstLaunchPhone.axml    
    ForgotPasswordPhone.axml    
    HeaderPhone.axml    
    HomePhone.axml
    LoginPhone.axml

Tablet  
    ChangePasswordTablet.axml
    DeviceBigListItemTablet.axml
    FirstLaunchGalleryItemTablet.axml
    FirstLaunchTablet.axml
    ForgotPasswordTablet.axml
    HeaderTablet.axml
    LoginTablet.axml
OutOfCoffee.axml
```

The Problem is: Xamarin.Android needs this flat folder structure :( Prebuildsteps, that flattens the folder are a bit tooo hacky.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual studio solution folder at the project level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922912/visual-studio-solution-folder-at-the-project-level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Our Solution for now:**

We use the nesting feature of Visual Studio. There are extensions which allow to define nesting for custom file types:

- [File Nesting](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c?SRC=VSIDE)
- [NestIn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45?SRC=VSIDE)

**Result:**

[image: File nesting in Visual Studio]